# Wordpress JSON API - remove characters from content

Tags: json, wordpress, api, character-encoding, json-api

I am using Wordpress JSON API plugin to get my posts as json. I am using that data for my AngularJS project. How to remove characters and p tags from content part of post that I get via JSON api.

```
<p> Lorem ipsum text &#8220;times&#8221; </p>
```

So I can on my page just show:

```
Lorem ipsum text "times"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but then realized that I was appending the content as textNode. After I set it as innerHTML it worked.

So, my wrong code was:

```
var content = document.createElement('div');
content.setAttribute('class', 'story');
var contentText = document.createTextNode(post.content);
div.appendChild(contentText);
```

Correct code:

```
var content = document.createElement('div');
content.setAttribute('class', 'story');
content.innerHTML = post.content;
```

Hope it will help someone.